# How to row differents column with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am working on  a long riperian buffer that crosses the boundaries of 20 cities. My buffer is subdivided in the same layer, in 20 sections that correspond to the limits of the cities. Each section is divided into multiples sections that represents the recreational potential of the site. That makes roughly 300 polygons. In my attribute table, i have a field « ID » that is empty. I need to row that field according to the cities corresponding to my polygons.

This is what tried to do. At first, i am trying to row my « city » field. Then i try to row the « ID » field according to the order newly created by the row « City » command. It doesn't work. When i ask QGIS the request " City = @row_number " it mix everything up. My polygons that were, up to that point, accurately identified, are modified. For instance, a polygon identified to the city X is now identified to the city Y.

Do you know i could row all my polygons according to their cities ?

Ex :  ID 1 / City X / Section 1
      ID 2 / City X / Section 2
      ID 3 / City Y / Section 1

P.S Excuse me for possible errors in the translation. The QGIS I am using is in French.

Comment: Give us a few screenshots with your tables and theirs attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that QGIS 2.14 has a new rownumber variable in the field calculator, I think this will allow you to do what you want.